# Variance of the simple regression coefficients $\text{Var}[\hat\beta]=\sigma^2 E[(X^T X)^{-1}]$ seems invalid? It seems to always blow up to $\infty$?

Tags: regression, variance, expected-value, regression-coefficients

Suppose for simplicity we consider simple linear regression with $n=2$ i.i.d. observations.

The conditional variance of the estimated least squares regression coefficients will be
$$
\text{Var}[\hat \beta|X]
=
\sigma^2 (X^T X)^{-1}
=
\sigma^2
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^2X_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^2 (X_i - \overline X)^2} & \dfrac{-\overline X}{\sum_{i=1}^2 (X_i - \overline X)^2} \\
\dfrac{-\overline X}{\sum_{i=1}^2 (X_i - \overline X)^2} & \dfrac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^2 (X_i - \overline X)^2}.
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For the unconditional variance, we have
$$
\text{Var}[\hat \beta]
=
E[\text{Var}[\hat \beta|X]]
=
\sigma^2 E[(X^T X)^{-1}]
=
\sigma^2
\begin{bmatrix}
E\bigg[\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^2X_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^2 (X_i - \overline X)^2}\bigg] & E\bigg[\dfrac{-\overline X}{\sum_{i=1}^2 (X_i - \overline X)^2} \\
E\bigg[\dfrac{-\overline X}{\sum_{i=1}^2 (X_i - \overline X)^2}\bigg] & E\bigg[\dfrac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^2 (X_i - \overline X)^2}\bigg].
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Lets consider one element of this matrix, for instance the simplest one, which is the bottom right element. We have
\begin{align}
E\bigg[\dfrac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^2 (X_i - \overline X)^2}\bigg] &= E\bigg[\frac{1}{(X_1 - \frac{1}{2}(X_1+X_2))^2 + (X_2 - \frac{1}{2}(X_1+X_2))^2}\bigg] \\
&= E\bigg[\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2}(X_1 - X_2))^2 + (\frac{1}{2}(X_2 - X_1))^2}\bigg] \\
&= \frac{1}{4}E\bigg[\frac{1}{(X_1 - X_2)^2 + (X_2 - X_1)^2}\bigg] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}E\bigg[\frac{1}{(X_1 - X_2)^2}\bigg] \\
\end{align}

Then
$$
E\bigg[\frac{1}{(X_1 - X_2)^2}\bigg] = \int \int \frac{1}{(x_1 - x_2)^2}f_{X_1}(x_1) f_{X_2}(x_2) dx_1dx_2
$$

We have a division by zero in the integrand when $x_1 = x_2$. While we consided the $n=2$ case here for simplicity, a similar situation will arise for the $n>2$ cases; we will have a zero in the denominator. This division by zero will give us an infinite expectation, which in turn will make the unconditional variance infinite.

So how can the expression for the unconditional variance of the estimated least squares regression coefficients be valid?

Comment: Have you noticed that the variance of the slope cannot be estimated with just two observations?  You need at least three.  In that case your analysis gives a triple integral.  Re-expressing it in spherical coordinates shows that there is no division by zero anywhere: the integrand remains bounded.

Comment: Ah yes it makes sense now